# Using STRING_SPLIT for 2 columns in a single table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've started from a table like this

```
ID | City                               | Sales
1  | London,New York,Paris,Berlin,Madrid| 20,30,,50
2  | Istanbul,Tokyo,Brussels            | 4,5,6
```

There can be an unlimited amount of cities and/or sales.

I need to get each city and their salesamount their own record. So my result should look something like this:

```
ID | City                               | Sales
1  | London                             | 20
1  | New York                           | 30
1  | Paris                              | 
1  | Berlin                             | 50
1  | Madrid                             | 
2  | Istanbul                           | 4 
2  | Tokyo                              | 5
2  | Brussels                           | 6
```

What I got so far is

```
SELECT ID, splitC.Value, splitS.Value
FROM Table
CROSS APLLY STRING_SPLIT(Table.City,',') splitC
CROSS APLLY STRING_SPLIT(Table.Sales,',') splitS
```

With one cross apply, this works perfectly. But when executing the query with a second one, it starts to multiply the number of records a lot (which makes sense I think, because it's trying to split the sales for each city again).

What would be an option to solve this issue? STRING_SPLIT is not neccesary, it's just how I started on it.

Comment: Don't store delimited strings in the database in the first place. You should have a separate table with columns `Id, City,Sales` with 5 rows for ID 1 etc

Comment: @MartinSmith 100% agreed. Sadly the provided data is not under my control

Comment: you need a string split function that returns an index column then so you can join the corresponding rows together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STRING_SPLIT()` is not an option, because (as is [mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) in the documantation) the *output rows might be in any order* and the *order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string*.

But you may try with a JSON-based approach, using [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and string transformation (comma-separated values are transformed into a valid JSON array - `London,New York,Paris,Berlin,Madrid` into `["London","New York","Paris","Berlin","Madrid"]`). The result from the `OPENJSON()` with default schema is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the `key` column is the 0-based index of each item in this array:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   ID int,
   City varchar(1000),
   Sales varchar(1000)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (ID, City, Sales)
VALUES   
   (1, 'London,New York,Paris,Berlin,Madrid', '20,30,,50'),
   (2, 'Istanbul,Tokyo,Brussels',             '4,5,6')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.ID, a.City, a.Sales
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT c.[value] AS City, s.[value] AS Sales
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(d.City, ',', '","'), '"]')) c
   LEFT OUTER JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(d.Sales, ',', '","'), '"]')) s 
      ON c.[key] = s.[key]
) a
```

Result:

```
ID  City     Sales
1   London   20
1   New York 30
1   Paris   
1   Berlin   50
1   Madrid   NULL
2   Istanbul 4
2   Tokyo    5
2   Brussels 6
```

Answer (score 1):

`STRING_SPLIT` has no context of what oridinal positions are. In fact, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) specifically states that it doesn't care about it:

> The order of the output may vary as the order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.

As a result, you need to use something that is aware of such basic things, such as [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).

Then you can do something like this:

```
WITH Cities AS(
    SELECT ID,
           DSc.Item,
           DSc.ItemNumber
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD(YT.City,',') DSc)
Sales AS(
    SELECT ID,
           DSs.Item,
           DSs.ItemNumber
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD(YT.Sales,',') DSs)
SELECT ISNULL(C.ID,S.ID) AS ID,
       C.Item AS City,
       S.Item AS Sale
FROM Cities C
     FULL OUTER JOIN Sales S ON C.ItemNumber = S.ItemNumber;
```

Of course, however, the *real* solution is fix your design. This type of design is going to only cause you 100's of problems in the future. Fix it now, not later; you'll reap so many rewards sooner the earlier you do it.

Comment: Yes - you either reap later ... or weep later!